# I want to know how to invoke a string input from another method

Tags: c#

I'm new in c#, and I'm trying to make a text game in a console application. I did this code for an example because I want to know how to invoke a string input from another method

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        b();
    }

    public static void b()
    {
        stops();
        c();
    }

    public static string stops ()
    {
        string stop = Console.ReadLine();
        //here i get the user input
        Console.WriteLine(stop);
        return stop;
    }

    public static void c()
    {
        string stop = stops();

        Console.WriteLine("i need this:" + stop);
        // here i want the user input
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

in this case, I didn't receive in the console the user input `stop`

I want to hold in my game the user name, but I'm using a lot of methods. In one method I ask the user his name, but I can't use his string in another method.
Now I'm trying to simplify my question, in the next example, the console application doesn't print here `Console.WriteLine("your name is: " + name);` this input `string name = Console.ReadLine();`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("what is your name:");
        userName();
        string name = userName();
        Console.WriteLine("your name is: " + name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string userName ()
    {         
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        return name;        
    }
}
```

Comment: `b` is calling `stops()` to read user input, then throwing it away. The *second* user input will be stored in `stop`. You've split up the code into ambiguously named methods, which makes it hard to debug. I'd start by removing some of the methods which aren't helping (move the code of `c` into main and remove `c`, remove the method `b`)

Comment: Also, to help us help you, update your description with some discussion of what you're trying to do. We want to help you, but it's a little hard to figure out what exactly you're after, because your code doesn't tell us a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your simple example is that you are calling the method twice - the first time you aren't capturing the output, and the second time you are. If you simply remove the first call to `userName()`, your code should work fine.

Here's a modified example:

```
static void Main()
{
    string name = GetUserName();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name + ". Nice to meet you!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static string GetUserName()
{
    Console.Write("Please enter your name: ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    return name;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

Now, if you want to use the `userName` throughout your program, you might consider setting it as a class-level variable. This means that all the methods in your class will have access to it.

Notice also that now you don't have to capture the output of the `GetUserName` method, because it will set a variable that you have access to already. We just call `GetUserName`, and then the `GreetUser` method has access to it:

```
// Variable set at this scope will be accessible to the whole class
private static string userName;

static void Main()
{
    GetUserName();
    GreetUser();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void GetUserName()
{
    Console.Write("Please enter your name: ");
    userName = Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void GreetUser()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + userName + ". Nice to meet you!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already answer your own question in your code.

In this case, when you have stops() that return the user input and c() that calls stops() again, which will ask for user input again. Based on your question, you want to take a string input from another method, which you already did in the c(). If you are trying to ask user input once only, then you can remove the stops() method inside the b() method.

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Init();
        }

        public static void Init()
        {
             AskUserInput();
        }

        public static string stops()
        {
             string stop = Console.ReadLine();
             //here i get the user input
             Console.WriteLine(stop);
             return stop;
        }

        public static void AskUserInput()
        {
             string stop = stops();
             Console.WriteLine("i need this:" + stop);                 
        }
 }
```

Also, as Rob mentioned, it's good practice to name your method with proper name. As later on when you start dealing with large project, this will help you a lot.

I also removed the last Console.ReadLine as I'm not sure what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code after you edited your question is just fine with one slightly change.  You don't have to call twice the method `userName()`.  The first time the program is waiting for your input is from when you are not assigning the returned value to any variable.  Then it is waiting for input again and there is where stores de variable and give you an output.

You just have to comment the line before string name ...

Here is your code working:  [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QIz6FM)